# Angular Universal (Platform Server) : SyntaxError: Unexpected token import : for external modules

Tags: prerender, angular-universal, platform-server

Am following [this guide](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/68/Make-your-Angular-App-SEO-Friendly-(Angular-4-+-Universal)) to enable universal rendering for my angular cli app using angular platform server. I have also updated my angular-cli and angular versions to the latest available.

All works well and I can see the pre rendering happen, except when I add an external module like [ngx-facebook](https://github.com/zyra/ngx-facebook)

When any external module is added, ts-node complaints about

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
```

This happens with every external module I use like ngx-cookie or ng2-sticky which makes me think I am missing some setting in my tsconfig.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You're not missing anything. Unfortunately some libraries are shipped in es6 format which cause your output bundle to include `import`/`export` statements which are not currently supported by Node, out of the box.
You can find [more about this issue here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7200). [This comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7200#issuecomment-322398334) suggests some workaround solves import/export problem but causes new set of problems for me! You can give it a shot anyways.